# Lag on CircuralProgressIndicator in JetpackCompose and DataStore

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am experiencing lag on CircularProgressIndicator, but I can't find the issue. Everything is on Dispatcher.IO. It might be because it's first screen, but can I resolve it somehow?

The issue occurs only after first app launch.

**What I've tried:**
I've tried adding Dispatchers.IO to each call that executes IO operations

**Expected result:**
CircuralProgressIndicator doesn't lag

**Screen:**

```kotlin
@Composable
@RootNavGraph(start = true)
@Destination
fun SplashScreen(
    stateProvider: () -> MutableStateFlow<MainActivityState>,
    onEvent: (MainActivityEvent) -> Unit,
    onNavigate: (Direction) -> Unit,
    uiEvent: StableHolder<Flow<UiEvent>>
) {

    val state = stateProvider.invoke().collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LaunchedEffect(lifecycleOwner.lifecycle) {
        lifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            uiEvent.item.collectLatest { event ->
                when (event) {
                    is UiEvent.Navigate -> {
                        onNavigate(CentralReturnsNavGraph)
                    }

                    else -> Unit
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(drawable.ic_logo),
            contentDescription = "App Logo"
        )
            CircularProgressIndicator(
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                modifier = Modifier.alpha(0.8f)
            )

        Text(
            text = "Loading...",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
    }

    if (!state.value.dictionary?.keys.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        scope.launch {
            delay(2000)
            onNavigate(CentralReturnsNavGraph)
        }
    }

}
```

**ViewModel:**

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dataSource: PreferencesDataSource,
    private val interceptor: Interceptor,
    private val url: Url,
    private val refreshTimeService: RefreshTimeService,
    private val dictionaryUseCase: GetDictionary,
    @Dispatcher(Dispatchers.IO) private val dispatcherIO: CoroutineDispatcher
) : ViewModel() {

    var state = MutableStateFlow(MainActivityState())
        private set

    private val _uiEvent = Channel<UiEvent>()
    val uiEvent = StableHolder(_uiEvent.receiveAsFlow())

    init {
        state.stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(stopTimeoutMillis = 5_000),
            initialValue = MainActivityState(isLoading = false)
        )
        saveDictionary()
    }

    fun onEvent(event: MainActivityEvent) {
        when (event) {
            MainActivityEvent.OnNavigateToApp -> {
                viewModelScope.launch(dispatcherIO) {
                    _uiEvent.send(UiEvent.Navigate)
                }
            }

            MainActivityEvent.SaveDictionary -> {
                saveDictionary()
            }

            MainActivityEvent.HideErrorDialog -> {
                hideErrorDialog()
            }
        }
    }

    fun saveUserData(userData: UserData) {
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcherIO) {
            dataSource.setUserData(userData)
        }.invokeOnCompletion {
            setToken()
        }
    }

    private fun setToken() {
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcherIO) {
            interceptor.setRefreshToken(dataSource.userData.first().token)
        }
    }

    fun refreshTime() {
        refreshTimeService.refreshParrotTime()
    }

    private fun saveDictionary() {
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcherIO) {
            dictionaryUseCase.invoke().collectLatest { response ->
                when (response) {
                    is Result.Success -> {
                        updateDictionary(response.data!!)
                    }

                    is Result.Loading -> {
                        loadingState(response.isLoading)
                    }

                    is Result.Error -> {
                        showErrorDialog(response.message!!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun deleteDictionary() {
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcherIO) {
            dataSource.deleteDictionary()
        }
    }

    private fun loadingState(isLoading: Boolean) {
        state.value = state.value.copy(
            isLoading = isLoading
        )
    }

    private fun showErrorDialog(message: String) {
        state.value = state.value.copy(
            showDialog = true,
            errorMessage = message
        )
    }

    fun changeIfOpenedFromParrot() {
        state.value = state.value.copy(
            isOpenedFromParrot = true
        )
    }

    private fun hideErrorDialog() {
        state.value = state.value.copy(showDialog = false)
    }

    private fun updateDictionary(dictionaryKeys: List<DictionaryKeys>) {
        state.value = state.value.copy(
            dictionary = Dictionary(
                keys = dictionaryKeys
            )
        )
    }
}
```

**UseCase:**

```kotlin
class GetDictionary @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository,
    private val dataSource: PreferencesDataSource
) {
    suspend operator fun invoke(): Flow<Result<List<DictionaryKeys>>> = channelFlow {
        dataSource.dictionary.collectLatest {
            if (it.keys.isEmpty()) {
                repository.getDictionary().collectLatest { result ->
                    when (result) {
                        is Result.Success -> {
                            send(Result.Success(result.data!!))
                            dataSource.setDictionaryData(Dictionary(result.data!!))
                            close()
                        }

                        is Result.Loading -> send(Result.Loading(result.isLoading))
                        is Result.Error -> {
                            send(Result.Error(result.message))
                            close()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                send(Result.Loading(false))
                send(Result.Success(it.keys))
                close()
            }
        }
    }
}
```